# How to display an error message to a user?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I created a like button in my solid-js app that does not allow someone to like a post they authored. For this, I wrote the following code:

```
const isPostAuthor = postAuthor.authorId === currentUser.id;
    if (isPostAuthor) {
      return next({ 
        status: 401, 
        message: "You can`t add a like on your own post"
       });
```

In order to check if the user who likes is the author of the post and to return an error message with status `401` to the user if it is the case. It works fine only that the error message is not displayed to the user instead, it instead displays a red cross to the user; However, this message is displayed on the command line. I thought it was a status error, so I changed the error status 401 to status `400` and then `404` but it still didn't show the error message to the user . So I tried out of curiosity the status 200 used for successful operations, it did return a message to the user but in green color yet the operation failed, I don't know why it works with the success code `200` but not with error codes . Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If my hypothesis is correct based on your explanation, wherever you are receiving this response, you need to add two sections to catch this response, one is `success` response and the other is `error` response, because as you said for `200` status code, it is showing the message and indicates the `success` response, that is the reason you could able to see the message for the user.

You can try adding `error` section in your code wherever you are receiving this response and see if you could able to catch this user message

hope my hypothesis helps :)